# How do I traverse in a single linked list to a specific node with name age and height?

Tags: c++

Now say theres a linked list with 4 nodes.With name age and height.
Now I want to move the pointer to the second node and 4th node so that I could insert a new node inbetween the 2nd and 3rd node of the linked list.

How will I go about this and how will I add values of name, age and height in the new node to be inserted?

The new node's values has to be inserted by the programmer and not the user.

Help will be much appreciated :(

Comment: I dont know :( And I have no idea how to increase that thing im just new to this

Comment: They're all about this linked list assignment. Perhaps he should have been paying attention in class?

Comment: You increase your rate by picking the best answer to each of your question, and hitting the checkmark next to it.

Comment: I am good in class , I ve just started out with C++ last semester.So it's all just new to me.Im only used to SQL and Visual basic

Answer (score 0):

OK...
Suppose it:

```
struct Node
{
    ...
    Node *next;
}

Node second, aux, third;
```

Algorithm:

```
second.next = aux;
aux.next = third;
```

Comment: so in this case aux is the second node?and third is the ...third node?

Comment: first... second was pointing to third, and you wanna put a node between them, so you have to create a tmp, aux, or "new second" node, and only you should change the "links" to the new nodes...

Comment: ok you lost me now...but to insert a new node,i should link aux->link to the newnode and the newnode->link to third.Right?I am afterall looking to insert a node between the second and third nodes

Comment: yup... i will take it: "I am afterall looking to insert a node between the second and third nodes "... i repeat again, you only have to change the "links" of your nodes... second will point to the aux node, and the aux node will point to the third node... it's simple...

Comment: okay..one last doubt hopefully..when assigning a value for a name ..for eg the name for the node...how does the code go? newnode->name="john"; ? cos I did that (name as char type with array size of 20 ) but it showed an error message...about some const char* and invalid conversion

Answer (score 0):

See the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

typedef struct _node_
{
    char *c1;
    char c2[];
    string str;
}node_type;
int main()
{
    node_type n;
    n.c1 = new char[6];
    n.c2 = new char[6];
    strcpy(n.c1, "HELLO");
    strcpy(n.c2, "HELLO");
    n.str("HELLO");
    cout << n.c1 << endl;
    cout << n.c2 << endl;
    cout << n.str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could I put those "char c2[];  " in the struct code itself and later on use it for the newnode i would insert?um wait...im trying to assign a name for a 'node' ...that wouldnt work for a node right?...strcopy(n.c2, "HELLO");  ...